Why is the OID available on the client, but not on the web service?
Follow up to the question posted here Using Microsoft.Identity.Web and Azure B2C. Authentication is working on both sides, the Windows client and the ASP.NET web service.
Now I want a unique identifier for the user on the web service so that when I call a method, I can map the OID to an access control list to limit the results returned to the client.
When I pull apart the claims on the client side, I clearly see an OID claim with the unique object identifier (which maps back to my Azure B2C user), but on the ASP.NET service, it's missing. What's odd is that I see other claims like the email address.
Why isn't the OID available in the 'User' property on the web service side? I thought that the claims on the client would be found on the service through the access token.

I think I found the issue. On the client, the claim is called 'oid'. On the web service, the object id is found in the claim called 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'. It would be great if someone could explain why they have two different ways of specifying the object id depending on which side of the conversation you're on.
